# Floating time cron job

Tags: linux, cron

I have a Linux host which I would like to have a cron job run on. I do not shut down this machine. I always suspend it. I want to run a job once a day  and I cannot set it for a particular time since my machine may or may not be running. I would like a cron job the first time a day when my machine comes live and not anymore throughout the day. Is that possible? Please do let me know, Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for anacron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is handled by `anacron`, which runs the default `cron.daily` etc. jobs on Fedora.

If this is a root job, you can either add it to the `/etc/cron.daily` or to `/etc/anacrontab`.

Comment: Just looked it up. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!